# LoadPackagedLibrary - how to package a DLL - any Samples out there?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

LoadPackagedLibrary - any tips on how to package a DLL?

The documentation on this doesn't actually say, and I can't find a sample.

Comment: Reference the following link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/8db1e07e-e41e-4293-93dd-1f1a9a8e5dab